# Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

i am trying to handle data in python using pandas , I have this data [image]

```
  import folium
    import pandas
    mapp = folium.Map(location=[19.997454,73.789803], zoom_start=6, tiles="Stamen Terrain" )
    fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="my map")
    
    df=pandas.read_csv("volcanoes.txt")
    cordinates="[" + df["LAT"].astype(str) + "," + df["LON"].astype(str) +"]"
    
    for i in cordinates:
        fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=i,popup="hey jayesh , welcome to Nashik",icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))
    
    mapp.add_child(fg)
    
    mapp.save("jay1.html")


> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.
> 
> Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
> 
> PS C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\python\volcano> &
> C:/Users/DELL/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe
> c:/Users/DELL/OneDrive/Desktop/python/volcano/jayesh.py Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "c:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\python\volcano\jayesh.py", line 10, in
> <module>
>     fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=i,popup="hey jayesh , welcome to Nashik",icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\folium\map.py",
> line 277, in __init__
>     self.location = validate_location(location) if location else None   File
> "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\folium\utilities.py",
> line 50, in validate_location
>     raise ValueError('Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, ' ValueError: Expected two (lat, lon) values for location, instead got:
> '[48.7767982,-121.810997]'. PS
> C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\Desktop\python\volcano>
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Please [include a minimal data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of your MRE.

Comment: In a quick scan of your error message, I notice that the cited argument is a single list, rather than two separate values.  Perhaps you need `*i` instead of `i`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

`cordinates="[" + df["LAT"].astype(str) + "," + df["LON"].astype(str) +"]"`

You are generating a string literal and passing that in.

Try replacing that line with:

`cordinates = [(lat, lon) for lat, lon in zip(df["LAT"],df["LON"])]`

This will generate a list of (lat, lon) tuples, which should work. I also don't think you need to cast them to `str`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> **it work for me like his**
> ```

```
import folium
    import pandas
    mapp = folium.Map(location=[19.997454,73.789803], zoom_start=6, tiles="Stamen Terrain" )
    fg = folium.FeatureGroup(name="my map")
    
    df=pandas.read_csv("volcanoes.txt")
    lat=list(df["LAT"])
    lon=list(df["LON"])
    
    for i,j in zip(lat,lon):
        fg.add_child(folium.Marker(location=[i,j],popup="volcanoes",icon=folium.Icon(color="green")))
    
    mapp.add_child(fg)
    
    mapp.save("volcanoes.html")
```